# How does a Shiro enabled web application handle CacheExceptions

Tags: java, caching, memcached, shiro

I have a question about handling `org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheException`.

What is shiro's responsibility when a cache exception occurs? This RTE ripples through the whole stack, but I'm unclear where it is handled and in what manner.

Can a shiro enabled web application recover?

Is the cache manager reinitialised?

Do I have to restart the application when a cache exception occurs?

For example, a timeout exception or a failed to connect to node exception occurs on cache.get(key). What's the expected outcome apart from bubble to the stop and die?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have checked all usages of CacheException and the only thing shiro does is throw it. It never gets catched let alone handled.

So the only expected outcome is to "bubble to the stop and die".

What you can do about it is have a servlet filter in front of shiro that catches this exception, then get a hold of the CacheManager instance (how you do that depends on your setup) and call cacheManager.getCache().clear() so the cache is reset.

Comment: I already know it bubbles and dies, and that if I need to stop it I need to intervene outside of shiro. Calling flush(clear) won't help in the two examples I suggetsted. Thanks